# How to import a component into another component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I have an ionic 5.0.0 application I'm facing an issue in importing a component into another.

I have 2 different modules in my application which are ChatPageModule and HomePageModule. I want to include Chat template in Home template (like ng-include). So my home screen will be split in 2. Left side will render home template and right side will render chat template simultaneously.

To achieve this I created a **SharedPageModule** as follows.

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { ChatPage } from '../chat/chat.page';

const routes: Routes = [
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [ChatPage],
  exports: [ChatPage]
})

export class SharedPageModule {}
```

After that, I imported the **SharePageModule** into **HomePageModule** as follows

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { SharedPageModule } from '../shared/shared.module'


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]),
    SharedPageModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

After I added the template selector of my Chat component into home template as follows.

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title text-center>HOME</ion-title>                
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content  class="homepage-content no-scroll" >
<ion-row>
...
</ion-row>

<ion-row>
 ...
 </ion-row>

<ion-row>  
<app-chat></app-chat> <!-- Here it is -->
</ion-row>

</ion-content>
```

Up to this everything was fine. now the issue starts.

I want to call some methods written in  ChatPage componennt from HomePage component. To do this I imported the Chat component in Home as follows.

```html
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ChatPage } from '../chat/chat.page'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  
constructor(private chat: ChatPage) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.chat.getMessages();
  }
  
 }
```

But I got below error when i navigate to my home page.

```html
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> ChatPage]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> ChatPage]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChatPage!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> ChatPage]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> ChatPage]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChatPage!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:21907)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

Comment: if i am not wrong we have somthing called app.module.ts right ? can you import your chat or shared module in the app.module.ts file ? Just give it a try

Comment: Please create a stackblitz reproducing the issue

Comment: try declaring both - u have added only Home page in declarations: [HomePage], try declarations: [HomePage,ChatPage]. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides everything, your error comes from the fact, that you didn't add a provider:

```
// home.page.ts

@Component({
  providers:  [ChatPage],
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting the `ChatPage` into the `HomePage` component, which is wrong. You don't need to inject anything. You just need to refer the instance of the `ChatPage`.

To do this, you can add a template variable in HTML, and use `@ViewChild` to read the component and call whatever method you want to call.

Comment: Hi Sachin Gupta Can you elaborate a little more with some sample codes?

Answer (score 0):

This is not following the standards of Angular, to accomplish this you can use Events :

1. Add the EventEmitter to your child component with the decorator @Output which will allow data to flow out of your component :

```
// chat-page.component.ts
// ...
@Output
onChat = new EventEmitter<string>();

/* Triggered when a user submit a message */
onSubmit(message: string) { onChat.emit(message) }

// ...
```

2. In your parent component template, listen to this event (`$event` is the data of the event)

```
<app-chat (onChat)="aParentComponentMethod($event)"></app-chat>
```

---

Or in your situation it looks like you only want to get the messages when your component is initialized, doing this using a component is a wrong pattern, you have to use services :

```
// chat.service.ts
// ...
private messages: Message[] = [];

getMessages(): Message[] { return this.messages; }

addMessage(message: Message): void { this.messages.push(message); }
// ...
```

Then you can use it in your both components (Chat and Home) :

```
// home.component.ts
// ...
constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.chatService.getMessages();
}
// ...
```

---

If you really want to call a method of your child component you can still use [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Links :

- [How to use @Output and @Input](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs)
- [Tutorial of Angular Services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)